# How to determine if a procedure was passed a file to standard input when run via the command line

Tags: command-line, stdin, openedge, progress-4gl

By running the procedure through the command line, pointing it to the input file like this

```
_progres -b -p test.p < test.txt
```

I can read the contents of test.txt into test.p with a simple

```
def var cline as c no-undo.
_tt:
do while true on endkey undo _tt,leave _tt:
import unformatted cline.
end.
```

However, if i don't pass a file to test.p, then without an explicitly open input, the error will be ** Attempt to read with no current source of input. (513). How to determine that a procedure was passed a file as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
/* isatty.i
 */
 
function isatty returns logical () in super.
```

and:

```
/* isatty.p
 * 
 * to use this:
 *
 *    run isatty.p persistent
 *
 *    {isatty.i}
 *    message isatty().
 *
 */

&IF "{&PROCESS-ARCHITECTURE}" = "64" &THEN
  &global-define XINT           int64
  &global-define LONGINT        int64
  &global-define PUTLONGINT     PUT-INT64
  &global-define GETLONGINT     GET-INT64
 &ELSE
  &global-define XINT           integer
  &global-define LONGINT        long
  &global-define PUTLONGINT     PUT-LONG
  &global-define GETLONGINT     GET-LONG
&ENDIF

define stream inStrm.

session:add-super-procedure( this-procedure ).

return.


procedure GetFileType external "kernel32.dll":
  define input  parameter fileHandle as {&LONGINT}.
  define return parameter result     as {&LONGINT}.
end.

procedure GetStdHandle external "kernel32.dll":
  define input  parameter fileHandle as {&LONGINT}.
  define return parameter result     as {&LONGINT}.
end.


/* determine if we are running with user input or redirected input
 *
 */

function isatty returns logical ():

  define variable result     as logical   no-undo.
  define variable tty        as character no-undo.
  define variable fileHandle as int64     no-undo.
  define variable fileType   as int64     no-undo.

  result = false.

  if opsys = "unix" then
    do:

      input stream inStrm through value( "tty" ).
      import stream inStrm unformatted tty.
      input stream inStrm close.
      if tty begins "/dev/" then
        result = true.

    end.
   else
    do:

      /* Windows stdin = -10    */

      run getStdHandle( -10, output fileHandle ).

      run getFileType( fileHandle, output fileType ).

      /* 0x0000 = unknown
       * 0x0001 = disk
       * 0x0002 = character (CON or LPT etc)
       * 0x0003 = pipe
       * 0x8000 = remote (unused?)
       */

      if fileType = 2 then
        result = true.

    end.

  return result.

end.
```

test it with:

```
/* testtty.p
 */

run isatty.p persistent.
   
{isatty.i}
message isatty().
 
quit.
```

Like so:

```
$ pro -p testtty.p
yes
```

and:

```
$ cat /dev/null | pro -b -p testtty.p > tty.out
$ cat tty.out
no
```

This is legal (but somewhat confusing):

```
$ pro -b -p testtty.p > tty.out
$ cat tty.out
yes
```

If you are doing that intentionally be aware that in such a case LASTKEY will be -1.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I assumed that I would have to catch stdin using the windows library, so I found a simpler solution for myself: I wrote a procedure in C ++ and use it as Input through

Comment: I assume that there's an equivalent Linux call?

Answer (score 0):

for windows I wrote a simple C++ program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,l;
    string str;
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    i = ftell(stdin);
    if (i == 0)
      return 0;
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

for UNIX i used the following code

```
DEFINE VARIABLE c AS C. 
define stream sin.
input stream sin through VALUE('[ ! -t 0 ] && echo $(</dev/stdin) || echo ""').
DO WHILE TRUE ON ENDKEY UNDO,LEAVE:
   import stream sin unformatted c.
   MESSAGE c. PAUSE 0.
 END.
input stream sin close.
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on API calls, it might be simpler to do something like this:

_progres -b -p test.p -param test.txt

Then in your session, you can check the value of SESSION:PARAMETER, which holds whatever you specified in -param.